# Зачем нужен label HTML?

Tags: html, label

Объясните, для того чтобы не только запомнить но и понять, зачем нужен тэг label для select и т.п.?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp - повышает удобство интерфейса при использовании мыши, так как щелчок по тексту элемента `<label>` передается элементу с `id`, указанным в аттрибуте `for`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если речь именно про **тег**, то:

> Тег `<label>` устанавливает связь между определенной меткой, в качестве
>   которой обычно выступает текст, и элементом формы (`<input>`, `<select>`,
>   `<textarea>`). Такая связь необходима, чтобы изменять значения элементов
>   формы при нажатии курсором мыши на текст. Кроме того, с помощью
>   `<label>` можно устанавливать горячие клавиши на клавиатуре и переходить
>   на активный элемент подобно ссылкам.
>
> Существует два способа связывания объекта и метки. Первый заключается
>   в использовании идентификатора `id` внутри элемента формы и указании его
>   имени в качестве атрибута `for` тега `<label>`. При втором способе элемент
>   формы помещается внутрь контейнера `<label>`.

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1"><label for="check1">Lorem</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2"><label for="check2">Ipsum</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check3"><label for="check3">Dolor</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check4"><label for="check4">Sit amet</label>
```

[Источник](http://htmlbook.ru/html/label)

Если речь про всё же про **атрибут**, то:

> Атрибут предназначен для указания метки пункта списка, сокращённой по
>   сравнению с текстом внутри `<option>`. Если атрибут `label` присутствует,
>   то текст внутри тега `<option>` игнорируется и в списке выводится
>   значение `label`.

```
 <select name="question">
    <option label="Бах" value="1">Иоганн Себастьян Бах</option>
    <option label="Бетховен" value="2">Людвиг ван Бетховен</option>
    <option label="Шопен" value="3">Фредерик Шопен</option>
    <option label="Огинский" value="4">Михаил Клеофас Огинский</option>
   </select>
```

[Источник](http://htmlbook.ru/html/option/label)

Answer (score 2):

Сложно обьяснить. Но к примеру у тебя есть радиобатон.

- Тут текст а точка это сам радиобатон.

Так вот если нажать на тот текст под лейблом он будет так же включать радиобатон. 
Звучит тупо, но это его единственное применение что я нашел.